# Deleted my Photos.app accidentally

Tags: photos.app

I accidentally deleted my Photos.app from /Applications dir. I looked up the internet but couldn't find a way to get it back.

Where do I download it from?

[image: Deleted Photos.app]

**Update**

I held down Option key and clicked on the Photos.app and it asked me to create new Photos Library file. So my original question wasn't correct!

Comment: Have you checked your Trash? If you haven't cleared the Trash, you can just right click on the Photos app and say Put Back.

Comment: No I emptied my Trash. I had done this awhile ago.

Comment: So you deleted your photo *library*. Unless you had a backup, it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

How did you delete `Photos.app`. It's an required macOS app. It's like if you try to delete `System Preferences`.

[image]

Maybe you didn't see the app. Try to search it with Spotlight.

Comment: Updated the question with dialog that appears when I try to access Photos.app

Comment: So now you don't have any problem?

Comment: Yeah, it's fixed!

Answer (score -1):

**Recover Deleted Apps on iPhone**

**Open the App Store**

- Tap on App Store on iPhone

**Tap on “Updates” from the menu at the bottom → Tap on “Purchased”.**

- Tap on Purchased on iPhone

**Now, tap on “Not on This iPhone” menu on top.**

- Tap on Not On This iPhone

**Find the app that you deleted and want to re-install.**

- Tap on the cloud icon and the installation will begin.

---

**Download Purchased Apps from iCloud**

Alternatively, you can search for the purchased app on the App Store.

- Search Purchased Apps on iPhone

Comment: Though not explicitly mentioned the OP probably deleted Photos.app in macOS/OS X and not in iOS.